# Add CDATA Section in Existing XML String in Swift 3.0/ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, soap

I have xml/xml string as response that I am getting from one API, Now I need to send this xml in another API with CDATA section. So my question is, How Can I add CDATA section in existing XML or XML String.
This scenario is in Soap API in Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the xml

Code

```
<tem:InputSTR><![CDATA[ This is where you put your xml ]]></tem:InputSTR>
```

Please provide some code next time you post some question it will be more easy others to help you.